# Adding class does not work on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on click and on hover to which the **active** class is added.The problem is that when you go in DevTools and choose devices where there is no hover and click on the button, the **active** class is not added to it for the first time. But when you click the second time and subsequent, then everything works as it should. How can I solve this problem?

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");

$(button).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(button).toggleClass("active");
});

$(button).hover(function() {
  $(button).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.button.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button" href="#">BUTTON</a>
```

Comment: i can verify this on android13 and latest ff, but i´m pretty sure that the hover event still triggers, you are better of checking if `touchstart` is defined or not

Comment: I can't replicate that in devtools/responsive design mode (FF). It turns red when I click on it. As an aside: you're mixing native JS with jQuery for some reason(?), and your "button" is an anchor with a button class. Shouldn't that just be a `<button>` element, or maybe have an anchor element and call it "link" instead?

Comment: It's unclear what your use-case is when "there's no hover" - as clicking it would make it active, but when there is hover, clicking it would make not active.

Comment: Use css :hover instead of js

Comment: Now if you go to devtools and select a tablet or phone and click, you can see that for the first time active is not added

Comment: I need to use js because in a real example, I have an action, not a color change. Here just as an example

Comment: I imagine using jQuery distorts this nonsensical logic. Why not just code this in pure javascript (and also why use a hyperlink to use as a button instead of directly using a button? you have the art of complicating your life).

Comment: @MisterJojo can't see how jquery has any effect here vs the exact same code in vanilla js, other than perhaps getting mixed with how "hover()" event works, though there's no evidence of that.

Comment: @freedomn-m Maybe, but it's worth checking out. However, his example here does not replicate the malfunction he describes. And again, while jQuery may still seem useful to some, its code cannot be considered absolutely reliable either.

Comment: Maybe jQuery is simulating the mouseenter event used by `hover()` when you click (since you can't click on something without entering it).

Comment: @Barmar jQuery greatly complicates debugging, for me this is a major flaw.